# How can I split the column of a panda dataframe so that each new column correspond to a single value in the split column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this panda dataframe:

| System name | Rating | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| system1 | 1 | 12 |
| system1 | 2 | 156 |
| system1 | 3 | 16 |
| systemZ | 1 | 77 |
| systemZ | 2 | 56 |
| systemZ | 3 | 66 |
| systemY | 1 | 99 |
| systemY | 2 | 77 |
| systemY | 3 | 99 |

How can I split the `Rating` column so that each new column correspond to a single value in the split column. I.e., I'd like to obtain:

| System name | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| system1 | 12 | 156 | 16 |
| systemZ | 77 | 56 | 66 |
| systemY | 99 | 77 | 99 |

How can I do this with pandas?

---

To create the dataframe:

```
import pandas  as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'System name': ['system1', 'system1', 'system1', 'systemZ', 'systemZ', 'systemZ', 'systemY', 'systemY',
                    'systemY'], 
    'Rating': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'Count': [12, 156, 16, 77, 56, 66, 99, 77, 99]})
print(df)
```

Comment: `df.pivot(index='System name', columns='Rating', values='Count')`. [pivot documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly thanks! I eventually used `df.pivot(index='QA System', columns='Rating', values='Count').reset_index()` (ie, added `.reset_index()` to your code).